# mongorestore with duplicate key error is very slow

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have two dumps made by mongodump in the Mongo 3.6. Some piece of data in the first dump is duplicated in the second.
Then I do mongorestore to a newly created mongo 4.2.
Restoring the first dump is a fast process. But restoring the second dump takes **days** to complete and is **very slow**, seems it won't be finished never.

```
2021-01-23T18:15:45.829+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  11.7MB/28.7GB  (0.0%)
2021-01-23T18:22:22.576+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  17.5MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:22:22.576+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  17.5MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:28:18.095+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  23.9MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:28:18.098+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  23.9MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:28:18.286+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  25.7MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:34:18.032+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  29.8MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:34:18.032+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  30.0MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:34:18.286+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  31.6MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:40:23.234+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  35.0MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:40:23.235+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  35.0MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:46:32.682+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  42.0MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:46:32.683+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  42.0MB/28.7GB  (0.1%)
2021-01-23T18:46:33.286+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  46.1MB/28.7GB  (0.2%)
2021-01-23T18:52:59.538+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  49.0MB/28.7GB  (0.2%)
2021-01-23T18:52:59.538+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  49.2MB/28.7GB  (0.2%)
2021-01-23T18:53:00.286+0000    [........................]  db.collectionName  53.7MB/28.7GB  (0.2%)
```

There are a lot of errors like this during the restore process:

```
continuing through error: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.collectionName index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('56bc17b30cf22c1176fa3b80') }
```

I'm using the AWS EC2 m5.xlarge instance with EBS io1 volume. Utilization of the CPU is about 30 percent, read and write throughput of the EBS volume are about 1000-2000 ops/s.
Can anybody help me to boost up the speed of this process and to figure out why it's so slow?

Comment: seems like a storage performance limits issue ...  , are the both dumps in different EBS volumes?

Comment: no, it's one EBS and the first restore of the dump is fast, but the second restore of the second dump, that contains duplicate entries goes very slow.

Comment: duplicated will be ignored , they seems not related to the performance issue ...